# Calculate median for multiple columns by group based on subsets defined by other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, aggregate, plyr

I am trying to calculate the median (but that could be substituted by similar metrics) by group for multiple columns based on subsets defined by other columns. This is direct follow-on question from this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405426/calculate-metrics-for-multiple-columns-based-on-subsets-defined-by-other-columns) of mine. I have attempted to incorporate calculating the median via `aggregate` into the `Map(function(x,y) dosomething, x, y)` solution kindly provided by @Frank, but that didn't work. Let me illustrate:

Calculate median for A and B by groups GRP1 and GRP2

```
df <- data.frame(GRP1 = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"), GRP2 = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B"), A = c(0,4,6,7,0,1,9,0,0,8,3,4), B = c(6,0,4,8,6,7,0,9,9,7,3,0))

med <- aggregate(.~GRP1+GRP2,df,FUN=median)
```

Simple. Now add columns defining which rows to be used for calculating the median, i.e. rows with NAs should be dropped, column a defines which rows to be used for calculating the median in column A, same for columns b and B:

```
a <- c(1,4,7,3,NA,3,7,NA,NA,4,8,1)
b <- c(5,NA,7,9,5,6,NA,8,1,7,2,9)
df1 <- cbind(df,a,b)
```

As mentioned above, I have tried combining `Map` and `aggregate`, but that didn't work. I assume that `Map` doesn't know what to do with GRP1 and GRP2.

```
med1 <- Map(function(x,y) aggregate(.~GRP1+GRP2,df1[!is.na(y)],FUN=median), x=df1[,3:4], y=df1[, 5:6])
```

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
  GRP1 GRP2 A B
1    A    A 4 5
2    B    A 9 9
3    A    B 4 7
4    B    B 4 3
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Could do the same as Frank showed you in the previous post: `f <- function(x, y) median(x[!is.na(y)]) ; df1[, Map(f, .SD[, 1:2], .SD[, 3:4]), by = .(GRP1, GRP2)]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg This would be a very concise answer, as I don't have to code for every column separately. Unfortunately, I get the following error message: `> df1[, Map(f, .SD[, 1:2], .SD[, 3:4]), by = .(GRP1, GRP2)]
Error in `[.data.frame`(df1, , Map(f, .SD[, 1:2], .SD[, 3:4]), by = .(GRP1,  : 
  unused argument (by = .(GRP1, GRP2))`

Comment: You need to convert `df1` to a data.table ofcourse, i.e. `setDT(df1)`

Comment: Of course - thanks!

Comment: @DavidArenburg At the risk of exposing my ignorance: why does `.SD[, 1:2] and .SD[, 3:4]` code for columns 3:4 and 5:6, respectively?

Comment: Because we used the first 2 columns in the `by` statement so `.SD` is unaware of them anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)

df1[, .(A = median(A[!is.na(a)]), B = median(B[!is.na(b)])), by = .(GRP1, GRP2)]

   GRP1 GRP2 A B
1:    A    A 4 5
2:    A    B 4 7
3:    B    A 9 9
4:    B    B 4 3
```

Same logic in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(GRP1, GRP2) %>%
  summarise(A = median(A[!is.na(a)]), B = median(B[!is.na(b)]))
```

The original `df1`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  GRP1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  GRP2 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  A = c(0, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 8, 3, 4),
  B = c(6, 0, 4, 8, 6, 7, 0, 9, 9, 7, 3, 0),
  a = c(1, 4, 7, 3, NA, 3, 7, NA, NA, 4, 8, 1),
  b = c(5, NA, 7, 9, 5, 6, NA, 8, 1, 7, 2, 9)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(A = ifelse(is.na(a), NA, A),
         B = ifelse(is.na(b), NA, B)) %>% 
# I use this to put as NA the values we don't want to include
  group_by(GRP1, GRP2) %>% 
  summarise(A = median(A, na.rm = T),
            B = median(B, na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   GRP1 [?]
  GRP1  GRP2      A     B
  <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     A         4     5
2 A     B         4     7
3 B     A         9     9
4 B     B         4     3
```